# How to aggreate in html django

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

Wrote a excel format html metrics to represent the date wise counts

```
def get_detail(usr,dt):
   res = Dataset.objects.filter(user = usr, date = dt).values('expense')
   try :
      output=res[0]['expense']
   except IndexError:
      output=" "
   return output
```

above code is a function

```
def metrics_new(request, year = None, month = None):
   import calendar
   from datetime import *
   from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta 



   m = Profile.objects.filter(lead = 'sushanth' ,status='A')
   now=datetime.today()

   if not year:
      year = now.year
   if not month:
      month = now.month


   year = int(year)
   month = int(month)
   d = calendar.mdays[month]

   out_txt="<TABLE id=\"myTable\" class=\"tablesorter\">\n"
   out_txt += "<THEAD>"
   out_txt += "<TR>"

   out_txt += "<TH> LDAP </TH>"
   for i in xrange(1,d):
       date_format = now.replace( year = year , month = month , day = i )
       out_txt += "<TH>" + str(date_format) + "</TH>"
   out_txt += "</TR>\n"
   out_txt += "</THEAD>"
   s_no = 0
   for fetch in m:
      out_txt += "<TR>"
      ld = fetch.user
      out_txt += "<TD>" + str(ld) + "</TD>"
      for i in xrange(1,d):
          date_format = now.replace( year = year , month = month , day = i )

          out_txt += "<TD>" + str(get_details(ld,date_format)) + "</TD>"
      out_txt += "<TR>\n"
   out_txt +="</TABLE>\n"
   try:
    cal_date = date(int(year), int(month), 1)
   except ValueError:
    raise Http404
   prev_month = (cal_date + relativedelta(months = -1))
   next_month = (cal_date + relativedelta(months = +1))




   return render_to_response('metrics.html', {'table':out_txt,
                                'prev_month':prev_month,'next_month': next_month, }, 
                             context_instance = RequestContext(request))
```

I have generated the table and its working,how to aggregate the expenses at each row

output :

```
user 2011-02-01 2011-02-02 2011-02-03 2011-02-04.......2011-02-28
 x     2          4          5                           2
 y     1          2
 z                            4
```

but i want the out in below format

```
    user 2011-02-01 2011-02-02 2011-02-03 2011-02-04.......2011-02-28 total
 x     2          4          5                           2             13
 y     1          2                                                     3
 z                            4                                         4
```

- here i want to aggregate the data at
  the end ?
- is there any best way i can do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Argh, don't create HTML manually in your view. There's a whole template language for that.

Comment: @ daniel,i tried many ways but finally i did creating HTML Manually,can you please suggest me some lines of code example ?

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the HTML creating code from the view.

The view needs to create the needed variables for the template, and the template should deal with formatting. Perhaps create a list of users, and for each user, a list of length calendar.mdays[month], containing the expanses of this user, and a sum variable.

```
users_list = [{'username':'x', 'expense_list':[2,4,5,0,0,0,2], 'sum':13}, ...]
```

when you do it in the view, and have a list of expenses for each user, calculating the sum should be as easy as

```
user['sum'] = sum(user['expense_list'])
```

Then your template code should be simple:

```
{% for user in users_list %}
    <tr>
    <td>{{ user.username }}</td>
    {% for expense in user.expense_list %}
        <td>{{ expense }}</td>
    {% endfor %}
    <td>{{ user.sum }}</td>
    </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks a ton for answer,but i have a doubt here, my output is in this format,users_list = [{'username':'x', 'expense_list':1, 'date':2011-03-02}, {'username':'x', 'expense_list':2, 'date':2011-03-04},...] ,how to make this to users_list = [{'username':'x', 'expense_list':[2,4,5,0,0,0,2], 'sum':13}, ...]

Comment: Change your get_detail to return a list of the expenses of a user in a given date range.